# Get unique ID of Row As it is being created in the same query

Tags: c++, mysql, sql

I want to predict the Unique ID that I will get from the next row that will be created in MYSQL via C++

For example if I create a user in my database I want to predict the unique ID (Auto incremented) of the user that will be created in the database using one query. This is for security purposes so I have no real idea how to go about this. Any nudges in the right direction would be great, thank you.

To sum it up: I want to predict the next Unique ID of a user in a database and return it whilst the user is created, one last note, the Unique ID is auto incremented.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? how will this improve your security?

Comment: I want  to do this because i have a server that temporarily stores the information too, I want to prevent duplication of a user and their information.

Comment: @ScottBenton If I understand you correctly, you have a transaction server that is "caching" your data and a data server that is storing it ... and you want to make sure these stay in sync?

Comment: @ScottBenton You might then want to consider making the users unique, like for *example* you could make it so that their email is unique. That way you won't end up with duplicate users.

Comment: We add it to a database to use our data. But since our server needs something to reference this specific row of data it has to be returned at creation seeing as there is no other unique data column that we have access to.

Comment: @ScottBenton You can return the ID after creation, but there is no way you can accurately predict what the DBM will pick as a value for the next entry.  There are too many different factors (e.g. if you have 2 transactions that are both inserting users, 1 may have already claimed `N`, so you would get `N+1`, but there are only `N-1` entries that are committed in the database ...)

Comment: Yeah, I understand now Zac, that is quite the dilemma. Thank you very much for your answers you were very helpful as was everyone else who replied. I think I will revise the system and try to get the ID afterwards. and just add specific parameters that will ensure that they do not get duplicated. Thanks once again!

Answer (score 1):

You do not want to predict the value as there is no guarantee it will be anywhere close to accurate.

For example, if a something attempts to add a user, but fails, the auto increment field is usually already updated (so you may have users for 1...N, but since N+1 failed, the next ID would be N+2, not N+1).

You can use `mysql_insert_id()` to get the last id that was added by your connection, but you cannot really get a prediction for what the next value will be (at least not accurately).